# ADT for a TVM calculator

Tags: c#, validation, finance, constructor

I wanted to get some criticism for the below ADT. This is just a basic ADT that will be fed into a TVM calculator. Main purpose is to have it initialized and correct for input errors.

Full disclosure: I am modeling it after Code Complete 2 guidelines. You should notice `if` statements stating nominal cases first followed by error-checking in `else` statements. I am trying to come as close as possible to the guidelines in the book. However, it is difficult to grasp 900+ pages of material. Aside from the incompleteness of the class, what am I missing, or what would Code Complete 2 catch?

```
public class TVMData
{
public decimal DiscountRate;
public decimal PeriodLength;
public decimal CashFlowFromAsset;
public decimal CashOutFlow;   
public decimal PaymentFrequency;  

   decimal DiscountedCashFlow;

    public TVMData(){}

    public TVMData(double discountRate, double periodLength, double cashFlowFromAsset, double cashOutFlow, PaymentPerPeriod paymentFrequency= PaymentPerPeriod.Annual)
      : this(Convert.ToDecimal(discountRate), Convert.ToDecimal(periodLength), Convert.ToDecimal(cashFlowFromAsset), Convert.ToDecimal(cashOutFlow), paymentFrequency){}

    public TVMData (decimal discountRate, decimal periodLength, decimal cashFlowFromAsset, decimal cashOutFlow, PaymentPerPeriod paymentFrequency= PaymentPerPeriod.Annual)
    {
        this.PaymentFrequency = Convert.ToDecimal(paymentFrequency);

        if (discountRate>=0m) 
        {
           this.DiscountRate= discountRate;

            if (periodLength >= 1m)
            {
                this.PeriodLength = periodLength;

                if(cashFlowFromAsset >= 0m)
                {

                 this.CashFlowFromAsset=cashFlowFromAsset;

                   if(cashOutFlow <= 0m)
                   {

                    this.CashOutFlow = cashOutFlow;

                   }

                   else
                   {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Cash Out Flow must be less than or equal to Zero", "cashOutFlow");
                   }

                }

                else
                {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Cash Flow From Asset must be greater than Zero","cashFlowFromAsset");
                }

            }

            else
            {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Period Length must be equal or greater than One", "periodLength");
            }

        }

        else
        {
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Discount Rate must be greater than Zero", "discountRate");
        }


     }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That book is a little dated in some of its recommendation (although still a great book).  That particular IF-ELSE recommendation leads to the [ArrowCode anti-pattern](http://aspiringcraftsman.com/tag/arrow-anti-pattern/), a better way (at least it reduces congnitive load) would be to use Guarded Clauses ([see here too](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/))

```
public TVMData(decimal discountRate, decimal periodLength, decimal cashFlowFromAsset, decimal cashOutFlow, PaymentPerPeriod paymentFrequency = PaymentPerPeriod.Annual)
        {
            if (discountRate < 0m)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Discount Rate must be greater than Zero", "discountRate");
            if (periodLength < 1m)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Period Length must be equal or greater than One", "periodLength");
            if (cashFlowFromAsset < 0m)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Cash Flow From Asset must be greater than Zero", "cashFlowFromAsset");
            if (cashOutFlow > 0m)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Cash Out Flow must be less than or equal to Zero", "cashOutFlow");

            this.DiscountRate = discountRate;
            this.PaymentFrequency = Convert.ToDecimal(paymentFrequency);
            this.PeriodLength = periodLength;
            this.CashFlowFromAsset = cashFlowFromAsset;
            this.CashOutFlow = cashOutFlow;
        }
```

Your Code here converts double to decimal, you may have issues with calling functions not taking into account the smaller [range decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) has when compared to [double](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx)

```
public TVMData(double discountRate, double periodLength, double cashFlowFromAsset, double cashOutFlow, PaymentPerPeriod paymentFrequency= PaymentPerPeriod.Annual)
      : this(Convert.ToDecimal(discountRate), Convert.ToDecimal(periodLength), Convert.ToDecimal(cashFlowFromAsset), Convert.ToDecimal(cashOutFlow), paymentFrequency){}
```

I would also move these to private if I could.  Reducing the scope and visibility of data leads to more reliable/maintainable code by reducing coupling ([see here for better argument](http://typicalprogrammer.com/doing-it-wrong-getters-and-setters/) or [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073723/core-java/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html)).

```
public decimal DiscountRate;
public decimal PeriodLength;
public decimal CashFlowFromAsset;
public decimal CashOutFlow;   
public decimal PaymentFrequency;
```

Comment: Thank you for reviewing. I do not like the arrow pattern. I kept them public for all the wrong reasons it will eventually lead to the breaking of the abstraction. Would you mind providing me more detail on what you meant about decimal to double conversion? I need to keep the variables in the decimal state.

Comment: Decimal has an approximate range of (-7.9 x 10^28 to 7.9 x 10^28) / (100 to 28)
Double has an approximate range of ±5.0 × 10^324 to ±1.7 × 10^308
So you get a lot more precision in decimal but larger numbers in double.  When you do a conversion it can lead to round off errors (decimal to double) or an overflow exception (double to decimal)

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be referring to this advice in [Chapter 15](https://books.google.com/books?id=I-83BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA355&lpg=PA355):

> ### Plain *if-then* Statements
>
> Follow these guidelines when writing *if* statements:
>
> ***Write the nominal path through the code first; then write the unusual cases***  Write your code so that the normal path through the code is clear.  Make sure that the rare cases don't obscure the normal path of execution.  This is important for both readability and performance.
>
> […]
>
> ***Put the normal case after the* if *rather than after the* else** Put the case you normally expect to process first.  This is in line with the general principle of putting code that results from a decision as cloase as possible to the decision.

I think that it's pretty safe to disregard that advice.  A major consideration is that , the examples do not involve exceptions.  When writing code without the benefit of exceptions, that arrow of code formed by ever-deepening nesting made good sense.  Particularly, in C, it's common to write code with this idiom:

```
Resource *ptr1 = malloc(…);
if (SUCCESS == iffy_operation1_involving(ptr1)) {
    Resource *ptr2 = malloc(…);
    if (SUCCESS == iffy_operation2_involving(ptr2)) {
        …
    }
    free(ptr2);
}
free(ptr1);
```

But C# has exceptions and automatic memory management.  There's no point in writing code that way any more.  Instead, a more important observation is that there is one way to succeed, but many opportunities to fail along the way.  Therefore, it's better to write code linearly without nesting:

```
public TVMData(decimal discountRate, decimal periodLength, decimal cashFlowFromAsset, decimal cashOutFlow, PaymentPerPeriod paymentFrequency= PaymentPerPeriod.Annual)
{
    this.PaymentFrequency = Convert.ToDecimal(paymentFrequency);

    if (discountRate < 0m) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Discount Rate must be greater than Zero", "discountRate");
    this.DiscountRate = discountRate;

    if (periodLength < 1m) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Period Length must be equal or greater than One", "periodLength");
    this.PeriodLength = periodLength;

    if (cashFlowFromAsset < 0m) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Cash Flow From Asset must be greater than Zero","cashFlowFromAsset");
    this.CashFlowFromAsset = cashFlowFromAsset;

    if (cashOutFlow > 0m) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Cash Out Flow must be less than or equal to Zero", "cashOutFlow");
    this.CashOutFlow = cashOutFlow;
}
```

Note that your "abstract data type" is a very leaky abstraction.  Since everything is public, one could just bypass all of the validation by doing this:

```
TVMData tvm = new TVMData();
tvm.DiscountRate = -1m;
tvm.CashFlowFromAsset = -1000000m;
```

If you want to allow the data to be populated in that style, you should be using properties instead of exposing public members.

Comment: Def a big leak. I have no need for them to be public. Thanks for pointing that out. I will revise that. What I like about nominal case is it reads easier with the exceptions stashed away at the bottom of the if else. I do not like the arrow indentation either.what do you think of leaving the nominal case and and keeping the exceptions on the bottom while maintaining linear format?

Comment: _Don't_ stash away the exceptions at the bottom the way you originally wrote it — it leaves a huge separation between the `throw` and the `if` that triggered it, making the code _less_ readable. What you _can_ do instead, if you prefer, is to put all of the validation together, followed by all of the field initializations. But then it becomes less obvious which fields have been validated and which have not.

Comment: I'm seeing it. When seeing these blocks its easy to ascertain that it is a validation section.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the two existing reviews, both of which I agree with, I'd also question the wisdom of having five parameters for your method, especially considering the first four are the same type (decimal). I'd much prefer to construct a "parameter class", e.g.

```
public class DataParameters
{
   public decimal DiscountRate { get; set; }
   public decimal PeriodLength { get; set; }
   // etc.
}
```

(Note that `DataParameters` is a bad name, it should be a more meaningful name.)

You then populate that class like this:

```
var dataParameters = new DataParameters
{
   DiscountRate = discountRate;
   PeriodLength = periodLength;
   /// etc.
}
```

That way is less error prone: what if you accidentally switch `discountRate` and `periodLength` when calling the method? (Though that could be prevented by [using named arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx), of course.)

Your constructor would become:

```
public TVMData (DataParameters dataParameters)
{
   if (dataParameters.DiscountRate < 0m) 
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Discount Rate must be greater than Zero", "discountRate");
   this.DiscountRate = dataParameters.DiscountRate;
}
```

That way it would be easy to add additional parameters.

Or perhaps you could simply store `DataParameters` instead of `DiscountRate` etc. after all validation is complete, to comply with [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

---

Note that the class name `TVMData` violates Microsoft's capitalization rules: ["Do capitalize only the first character of acronyms with three or more characters"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Thank you for contributing! Really great to learn more! I see the point you are making. Would it change things if this class is actually the parameter class that goes into another ADT that calculates time value of money. If not you would still proceed with the decomposition into DataParameters? So then less arguments are fed into the constructor? Thanks again!!

Comment: @cnewb At that point it would be overkill, sure. But then perhaps I'd avoid using a multiple parameter constructor and instead consider moving the validation checks to a component. Maintaining methods and constructors with numerous parameters becomes a real hassle after a while, that's why usually I move to this "parameter pattern" once things tend to get complicated.